# Tailwind CSS drop-shadow class causing performance issues

Tags: css, vue.js, tailwind-css

I have recently lost some nerve over finding the cause of severely falling FPS in my application. The problem is that after using the app for a while, its performance drops very sharply, down to about 10FPS. Looking for the cause, I found that removing the **drop-shadow-md** class from the **@apply** directive solved the problem.

```scss
    @layer components {
        .standard-card {
            @apply rounded-md drop-shadow-md bg-surface-content-light dark:bg-surface-content-dark
        }
        /* other classes */
    }
```

In other threads I managed to find that everything related to the shadow causes a heavy load on the CPU. When dynamically rendering components it causes even more load. In my case, I render most of the components that use the standard-card class using a v-for loop.

```
<div v-for="chart in ltCharts" :key="chart" class="standard-card flex flex-col gap-2"> ...content... </div>
```

Are there any solutions to this problem?

**Stack:**

- Vue - 3.2.45
- PrimeVue - 3.29.2
- PrimeIcons - 6.0.1
- Vite - 4.3.9
- TailwindCSS - 3.3.2

**Tailwind configuration**

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  mode: 'jit',
  darkMode: 'class',
  content: [
    './index.html',
    './src/**/*.{vue,js,ts,jsx,tsx}'
  ],
  theme: {...}
}
```

**Probably related:**

[CSS - drop-shadow issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53186051/css-drop-shadow-issue)
[CSS Text-shadow performance issues.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6883511/css-text-shadow-performance-issues)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you have a background color on the element so with the information available, it seems like there isn't any transparent layering going on. This means you could consider using `box-shadow` instead of `filter: drop-shadow()` by swapping out `drop-shadow-*` for [`shadow-*`](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/box-shadow) which should be more performant:

```js
tailwind.config = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      backgroundColor: {
        'surface-content-light': 'red',
        'surface-content-dark': 'green',
      },
    },
  },
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

<style type="text/tailwindcss">
@layer components {
  .standard-card {
    @apply rounded-md shadow-md bg-surface-content-light dark:bg-surface-content-dark
  }
}
</style>

<div class="standard-card flex flex-col gap-2"> ...content... </div>
```

Comment: It looks like it works, such a small thing and it brought me so much work. I am very grateful to you!